# Building for ARM? Cannot do cross-compilation with `go install` when GOBIN is set

Tags: go, arm

Whenever I try and use 'go install' after settings goarch, goos and gobin I get 'cannot install cross-compiled binaries when GOBIN is set', but don't understand why?

What's the simplest way to build for arm linux?

Comment: Have you tried with the `build` command, instead of `install`? e.g. `GOARCH=arm go build`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the go build command instead:

```
env GOOS=android GOARCH=arm64 go build -o /arm64bins/app
```

Available `GOOS/GOARCH`'s in Go 1.7:

```
➜ go tool dist list | grep arm                                                                                   05/29/16
android/arm
android/arm64
darwin/arm
darwin/arm64
freebsd/arm
linux/arm
linux/arm64
nacl/arm
netbsd/arm
openbsd/arm
plan9/arm
```

Comment: `go install` supports passing multiple packages at once on the command line when they're all part of the same project (e.g.  `GOBIN=/path/to/bin go install mypkg/foo mypkg/bar`). But unlike `install`, `go build` cannot combine `-o` and multiple packages. So that bit of functionality seems lost.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me(cross compilation from win64 to linux arm6):
I first set these in terminal:

```
set GOARCH=arm
set GOBIN=D:\work\go\bin
set GOEXE=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=linux
set GOPATH=D:\work\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-fPIC -marm -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
```

and then simply:
go build
and it generates binary output for target (ok).
then copy binary output to the target system and run.
I think you should use "go build"  not "go install" for cross compilation.

Comment: You don't actually need so many variables. If you don't need CGO then no gcc needed. For go only builds you only need to set GOOS, GOARCH and GOARM

Comment: @creker: yes, My IDE set all automatically (for general case)